# What were modal verbs in third person singular in archaic English?

Tags: archaic-language

I know that modal verbs back in time were always the same (not changeable) with some exeptions - e.g.:
thou shalt, thou hast, thou dost, thou canst. Hence my question is: how to transform modal verbs in third person singular? How to say for example: she shall, she has, she does, she can, in archaic English?

Comment: She shall, she hath, she doth, she can.

Comment: So there are only four modal verbs that are exeptions:  is, doth, hath, dareth, is that right?

Comment: @KateBunting: [*She **canst**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22she+canst+not%22) WillS - [*He **durst**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22He+durst%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica No, it's _thou canst_. Only one of the examples you have found is an actual use of _she canst_, and that appears to be 'uneducated' speech.

Comment: @KateBunting: Usually, yes. The point of my post was that link to numerous matching instances in Google Books. And then I thought of ***durst*** as another "awlward" example.

Comment: Apropos "durst", this is a verb in past tense - does it ever change? I durst, we durst, thou durst, they durst, she durst, is it all correct?

Comment: I've found several lists of modal verbs online, and none of them contains _dare_. I'm not sure what you mean by 'back in time [they] were always the same'.

Comment: @WillS: I daresay it's interesting to *some* learners, but mostly they've no reason to fill their heads with usages which have no place in modern contexts.

Comment: [***He dursn't** speak like you and me!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22He+dursn%27t%22) (That's ***dares not***, not ***doesn't***)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica The example from _Clarissa_ is a false positive (the text is in two columns), and in two of the others there is punctuation between the two words.

Comment: I mean that modal verbs such as "shall" for exmaple, were never transformed, they would  always stay the same as they are today, but, back in time, there were some expetions as in third/second person. And "dare" is a modal verb, or semi modal to be correct,  when one ommits "to", for example "how dare you", "he dares challenge them"

Comment: @KateBunting: I actually looked specifically at [*whom she canst not take away,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22whom+she+canst.+not+take+away%22) but you can probably pick holes in that one too (preceding ***therefore Virtue are a Good*** doesn't look good! :) Whatever - I'm certainly not gonna maintain that any significant fraction of the population ever used forms like *He canst go to Hell!*

Comment: Yeah, I think that we can stick to "she/he can" and leave "canst" to thou only.

Comment: [***Canst thou, durst** thou*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22canst+thou+durst%22) leave all such usages in the past, where they belong?

Comment: Why... it is most fine, imo, to know a tittle of obsolete tongue, especially, since it's really easy to learn and still in use, for example in the north of England. Knowing those few archaisms is like a grasp of 400 years. Other languages tended to change a lot more faster and intensely, when English is almost the same as it was during Shakespearan times. To say or write some sht like "she runneth" would be probably out of place, for we don't even know how to pronounce it - TH like S or with grave/acute E, but saying to  your close mate "Where art thou" or "I love thee" makes the language hmm

Comment: sort of more complicated, prettier, has it put emphasis on ONE person. "You" is too formal in my opinion. It's interesting that many young people renew this archaic third person singular. I wonder if they give it up when it comes to say something like "Where you walkedst, wouldst thou tell me?" Nevertheless, saying some brief subtle phrases like: "Thy eyes" or "I told thee" is adorable